# xcode Trying to embed Video. No errors but no video either

Tags: xcode, video, embed

I am sure I am just missing something stupid but I have been stuck on this all day. Any help would be appreciated. I was trying to embed video in an ipad app. I am using xcode 4.2.5. I am following a tutorial which I found here: [embeded ipad video](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)

I have followed the instructions exactly as far as I can tell. I have started over several times. Before I was getting a memory error but this time I am not getting any errors at all. Only no video or audio. The only part of the tutorial I did not use was the last part about the ipad rotation because I'm not worried about that.

The only part I was unable to follow exactly was putting the video in the resources folder because xcode 4.5.2 does not make one. So I put MOVIE.MOV in the same directory as my .h, .m and .xib files were automatically placed in. I have tested the video and it does work on its own.

Here is the code: any help or guidance would be appreciated. Sorry for being such a NOOB.

the header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

}
-(IBAction) playMovie;
@end
```

the main:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)playMovie
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"MOVIE" ofType:@"MOV"]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
    initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayer];

    if ([moviePlayer
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }    
    [moviePlayer release];
}
```

Thankyou very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things you could check:

- Did you check the "Copy item to destinations group folder" when you dragged the movie onto the Xcode project?
- Does the item show up in the "Copy Bundle Resources" Build Phase? (click on the Project, Select your target and check the "Build Phases" tab in Xcode)
- Paths strings are case-sensitive on iOS. Does your movie really have the file name "MOVIE" and the extension "MOV" (all upper-case)?